# How To Dynamically Change The Color of Already Existing Polygon

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

So I am building an interactive choropleth map in Shiny with Leaflet for R. It uses the shape files for all counties in the United States, and it draws them as polygons. Additionally, there are characteristics of these counties which I would like to display (unemployment rate, % without high school education, etc.)

Rather than having to redraw the polygons every time I wish to display a new characteristic, I would rather update the underlying color of the polygons.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
ui <- fluidPage("Mapping Characteristics of the USA",
               fluidRow(
                        column(10, leafletOutput("map")),
                        column(2, radioButtons(inputId = "radio", selected=character(0), label="Characteristics",
                                               choiceNames = c("Unemployment Rate", "% w/out high school education", "% w/out insurance"),
                                               choiceValues = c("uer", "no_hs_per", "no_insur")))))

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  #Render the map
  output$map = renderLeaflet({leaflet(counties)})

   observeEvent(input$radio,
           { 
             #Create color function
             pal = colorBin(palette = topo.colors(10), domain = counties[[input$radio]], pretty=TRUE)

             #Redraw Map
             m = leafletProxy("map", session=session, data=counties) %>% clearShapes() %>%
               addPolygons(stroke=TRUE, weight=1, fillOpacity = 0.5, color = pal(counties[[input$radio]]))
           }) #End of observeEvent(input$radio, ...)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You'll notice in my code above that every time the user clicks on a radio button to see a new characteristic mapped I have to draw a new set of Polygons (even though it is the same set of polygons which is to say the counties of the USA). I want to be able to recolor the polygons instead since the map is a bit slow to update.

After some searching, it seems as if the ability to recolor the polygons doesn't exist yet in leaflet for R. It does exist in leaflet for Javascript though.

Examples of changing the color in Javascript with leaflet:
[Dynamically change the color of a polygon in leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606027/dynamically-change-the-color-of-a-polygon-in-leaflet)

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78069/how-do-i-set-the-fillcolor-of-polygons-in-leaflet-js-dynamically

My question is can someone show me how you would inject the javascript code for changing the color of the polygons into a shiny app?

Comment: I wonder if you want to use layers to change colors in polygons.

Comment: I thought about using layers. The only problem is you have to draw all the polygons ahead of time. Even with low resolution county shapefiles, the map is already a bit large (and I plan on adding more characteristics).